# only one request across different tabs

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html

In browser I have two tabs opened up having instance of same webpage.  On some event I want only one of them to perform certain activity (for eg. Calling 3rd party web service). Both of them should not make the same request. The page uses JavaScript only.

I have my own .net backend also. The backend is used for http (REST API) request.

Following image also try to explain the problem:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be an [XY-problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem)

Comment: when you say 2 tabs open at the same time.. please explain this because you can display 2 tabs but only one of them can have focus so please explain better

Comment: What if someone opens a different browser on the same machine to the same URL?

Comment: We are looking at only 1 scenario where user has one browser but two tabs. We are ignoring the case of two browsers.

Comment: Actually, the webpage is based on XMPP-BOSH events. So event comes for all the instances of the page. For eg. Events comes “its 3AM and u still at this page. Save this info to 3rd party server”. Now out of two instances of the page opened. Only one of them should make the request to 3rd party server.